# MouseClick on Panel skips clicks

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Panel on a Form with a MouseClick event. The problem is that the MouseClick event isn’t fired every time I click the panel. It’s very random when it skips a click.

I guess I could use MouseDown and MouseUp event instead, but I’d like to know why this is happening...(I have the same problem when I use "Click" event)

I’ve tested this outside my project with a very simple test project and it’s still doing it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var panel = new Panel
        {
            Location = new Point(10, 10), 
            Size = new Size(200, 200),
            BackColor = Color.Red
        };
        panel.MouseClick += panel_MouseClick;
        //panel.Click += panel_Click; --Also skips clicks.

        this.Controls.Add(panel);
    }

    void panel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Click");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Panel class has ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick turned on.  So you are quite likely to generate MouseDoubleClick events, you don't see them since you didn't subscribe the event.

More than one way to fix that beyond turning off the style flag and subscribing that event as well, the MouseDown event is an alternative for example.  Turning off the style requires deriving your own class from Panel with just a constructor that calls SetStyle().

Comment: Thank you very much! I've gone for the option to derive my class from Panel and called SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, false) in the constructor